# jQuery get element that triger function

Tags: jquery, html, function

all!I'm a beginner in jquery. I need to get an element that I clicked. To move to their neighbors and get their values.

```
<td>21</td>
<td>Peter</td>
<td>Admin</td>
<td onclick=fillEditForm()>Edit record</td>
```

So i need click "Edit record" and get by jquery text of previous `<td>` tags (21,Peter,Admin).
The function must look like that i think

```
    function fillEditForm(obj){    
    alert(obj.prev().text());
    }
```

Comment: Pass `this` to click handler `onclick="fillEditForm($(this))"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<td onclick=fillEditForm(this)>Edit record</td>


function fillEditForm(obj){    
    alert($(obj).prev().text());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `this` like this `fillEditForm(this)` and using `$(obj)` with `parent().find()` or `prev()`, you can get any of your previous `td` elements.

You can use `$(obj).parent().find('td:not(:last-child)').text()` to get values together.

Or

You can loop through and get each text `$(obj).parent().find('td:not(:last-child)').each(function() {`

Or

You can use `$(obj).parent().find('td:not(:last-child)').map(function() {` to get all text in an array

```js
function fillEditForm(obj) {

  console.log($(obj).parent().find('td:not(:last-child)').text()); // get all td except last

  console.log($(obj).prev().text()) //get prev text

  //get each separately
  $(obj).parent().find('td:not(:last-child)').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });

  //get results in an array
  var results = $(obj).parent().find('td:not(:last-child)').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  console.log(results);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Admin</td>
    <td onclick=fillEditForm(this)>Edit record</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a class to the td that you click
2. Use this context to tell the clicked td
3. Use closest to get the parent tr
4. Use .map() to create an array of all td in the tr except the clicking td

```js
$(".edit").click(function() {

  var arr = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:not(.edit)').map(function() {


    return $(this).text();
  }).get();

  console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>james</td>
    <td>user</td>
    <td class="edit">Edit record</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Admin</td>
    <td class="edit">Edit record</td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` to inline click handler.

```
<td onclick="fillEditForm(this)">Edit record</td>
```

And modify the function as

```
function fillEditForm(obj) {
  var arr = $(obj).siblings().map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  console.log(arr)  
}
```

---

However I would recommend unobtrusive event handler. Use correct semantic element as assign event handlers. then various DOM traversal methods can be use to get the desired information.

```js
function fillEditForm() {
  var arr = $(this).closest('td').siblings().map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
  console.log(arr)  
}

$('.fillEdit').on('click', fillEditForm)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Admin</td>
    <td><button class="fillEdit">Edit record</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```